# Table stacked in mobile

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a table in my aura component. I use class="slds-max-medium-table_stacked but I can't see header. I want result as in the link:
[How to present a lightning-datatable on mobile devices?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310447/how-to-present-a-lightning-datatable-on-mobile-devices/310462#310462)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this we can simple add data-label="Label" to our  tag:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Appraisal Name</th>
                <th>Advertised Price</th>
                <th>Customer Trade Value</th>
                <th>Trading Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="slds-text-body_regular">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.appraisals}" var="appraisal">
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Appraisal Name">{!appraisal.Name}</td>
                    <td data-label="Advertised Price">Test</td>
                    <td data-label="Customer Trade Value">Test</td>
                    <td data-label="Trading Value">Test</td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```